# aibo Web API による deviceId の取得方法

Tags: api, aibo-developer

https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#introduction

上記サイトの手順でトークンは取得しましたが、次の「deviceId の取得」で止まっております。
「deviceId を取得する API を実行することで取得できます。」と書かれてますが、
「deviceId を取得する API」をクリックして出る画面から、何をどうすれば良いのか、
判りません。

wifi windows10 chrome の環境はあります。
htmlエディタ、ftpソフト、レンタルサーバーはあります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @keitaro_soさま
コマンドプロンプトから実行出来、お陰様で解決しました。
curl -X GET https://public.api.aibo.com/v1/devices -H "Authorization:Bearer トークン"の後、enter でdeviceIdを得ることが出来ました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんにちは。

私から既にFacebookやTwitterで回答を差し上げましたが、
WindowsとUnix(Mac含め)とでは若干記載が異なります。これは「(円マーク・バックスラッシュ)」「^」「"」「'」に対するエスケープ文字の有無や違いがあります。

Windows10ではコマンドプロンプトを起動し

```
 chcp 65001
```

として文字コードをUTF-8にした後に

```
curl -X GET https://public.api.aibo.com/v1/devices -H "Authorization:Bearer xxxx"
```

で取得できます。(xxxxはご自身のトークンです)

結果として

```
{"devices":[{"deviceId":"ここは英数字の並び","nickname":"ご自身のaiboの名前"}]}
```

が取得できればOKです。多頭飼いの場合は複数返答です。

ちなみに、プログラミング言語「Python」のコードで取得する場合は、以下のようになります。(xxxxはご自身のトークン)
※PCで環境を構築しなくても、今のところオンライン開発環境からもRequestは飛ばせて受け付けてくれるようです。

```
# coding: utf-8

import requests
import sys
import json
import time

get_url = 'https://public.api.aibo.com/v1/devices'
token = 'xxxx'

response = requests.get(get_url, headers={ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,})

get_result = json.loads(response.text)
print(get_result)
```

---

aibo APIの利用は2種類あり、
上記は中級～上級者向け（プログラミング経験者向け）になります。
こちらは技術的なところとして「Windows/Unixコマンド」、通信処理「Http Request(GET,POST)」「JSON」の扱い、プログラミング言語「Python」あたりをある程度理解していることが前提となっているようです。

もう1つ初心者向けの「ビジュアルプログラミング」は、指示や命令のパーツを組み合わせるだけで、上のような難しい書き方をしなくてもよいものですので、こちらから始められてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: @Takさま、ご丁寧にありがとうございます。　　　　
「Windows/Unixコマンド」は少し、CGIは既成のに少し手を入れられる程度、
JavaScriptは以前に少し触った経験がある程度で、全て初心者ですが。
でもaiboに後ろ向きでなく、こちらを向いてして欲しいことがあります。　　　　
現在、aiboビジュアルプログラミングにトライしておりますが、効果がパソコンの前で、その時だけ、のようです？　　　　
が、デモのように「ティッシュを加えることを覚えさせる」ことが出来るのはPythonかな？と思えるのですが、可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.aibo.com/jp/docs#getdevices
内の

> Example request

にはCurlで記述してありますのでCurlコマンドが実行できる環境がありますか？
Windows10環境の最新であればコマンドにプリインストールされているでしょう。

「Windows」キーを押しながら「R」キーを押すと、「ファイル名を指定して実行」ウィンドウが表示されます。 名前欄に「cmd」を入力し、「OK」をクリックします。 すると、「コマンドプロンプト」ウィンドウが起動します。

そこで

```
curl -V
```

と記述してバージョン情報があれば利用できます。

> 'curl' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、 操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。

と出ると残念ながら利用できません。

もしくはレンタルサーバでSSHが利用できればもしかすると実行できるかもしれません。レンタルサーバの仕様を確認してください。

ちなみにですが、
WebAPIは基本はシステムやアプリ同士が利用するものなので、人とシステムをつなぐブラウザ経由で利用するものではないです。Webの仕組みを使っていますが、非常にシステムチックなやり取りになります。

コマンドラインもしくは何かしらのサーバサイドの言語が利用できればより使えると思います。
あとは「WebAPIとは」みたいな感じで検索してもらってもどのようなものなのか理解できると思います。

参考サイト
https://qiita.com/NagaokaKenichi/items/df4c8455ab527aeacf02
https://developer.ntt.com/ja/blog/5%E5%88%86%E3%81%A7%E5%88%86%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8BWebAPI